# Do I need a key pair to encrypt with gpg if there is no recipient?

Tags: pgp

I want to encrypt a file and be able to decrypt/encrypt it again only for me to use that file.

If I use a key pair to encrypt the file, then I need to move the key files around to new devices if I want to decrypt it there. But that is not very convinient, and if only I am going to use the file, it is nescessary to have a key pair then, or is it enough to just use `gpg --symmetric file.example` and make the file only ask for a password and not requiring key files as well?

Summary:
Is it recommended to encrypt a file with `gpg --symmetric` so that decrypting the file only requires the correct password to be provided if only one person(me) is going to use it? Compared to creating a key pair and using the key pair to encrypt/decrypt, in which case I will have to have the key files with me if I want to decrypt on a different device.

Comment: I do that all the time.  Just use a long enough passphrase (80 bits should do it, which means about 7 diceware words if I recall, or if you're using random printable characters about 12-13 characters.  More than that is fine, but 80 bits is plenty unless you're being specifically targeted by some nation-state :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a passphrase is fine. GPG contains outdated crypto and can be misused, I'd suggest [age](https://age-encryption.org/) as a better option.

Comment: Thanks for answer, what do you mean with being misused?

Comment: You can specify using insecure ciphers with it. Age doesn't let you do that by simply only including secure methods.

Comment: Okey, but the default cipher used in gnupg 2.1 is AES-128, so if I use the default, then it should be secure?

Comment: As long as you pick a secure enough passphrase (10 diceware words is enough), yes. And preferably sign the files after encrypting as well if you're going to upload any of them to cloud backup servers.